# „Ersti“ – woher kommt das Wort?

Tags: etymology, colloquial, austrian

Ich habe gerade gesehen, dass es in München zum Semesteranfang ein für mich neues Wort gibt, nämlich *Ersti*.
Woher kommt das? Gibt es das schon woanders in Unistädten? Oder ist es neu?
Wie ist es in Österreich?

Comment: Steht übrigens auch im Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ersti

Comment: Schon im Duden? Sorry, das wußte ich nicht.

Comment: Ähnlich wie beim englischen _freshie_ statt _freshman_ kann man auch _Ersti_ – manchmal auch _Erstie_ geschrieben – den positiven Aspekt der Geschlechtsneutralität schwer absprechen. Vereinzelt hört man allerdings von der _Erstine_, genauso wie von der _Azubine_ oder _Hiwine_, aber bisher weder von der _*Studine_ noch der _*Assine_, obwohl die movierten Formen der Langfassungen unterschiedlich gebildet werden: _?Erstsemesterin_, _Auszubildende_, _Hilfswissenschaftlerin_ (eigentlich _studentische_  oder _wissenschaftliche Hilfskraft_: _SHK_ bzw. _Wihi_).

Comment: An manchen Unis heißt es übrigens Ersi.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zumindest in ganz Deutschland ist es gut bekannt.

Wer neu an der Universität zu studieren anfängt, steigt im ersten Semester ein, ist also ein *Erstsemester.* Da einige *Studis* an der *Uni* einen veritablen *Aküfi* haben, ist der lange Ausdruck ihnen zu lang, und sie kürzen es auf *Ersti,* analog zu *Profs,* dem *Asta* oder dem *Audimax.*

---

Erklärungen:
Uni = Universität
Prof = Professor
Studi = Student
Ersti = Erstsemester
Audimax = *Auditorium maximum*
Asta (eig. AStA) = Allgemeiner Studentenausschuss
Aküfi = Abkürzungsfimmel.

Comment: Aküfi kannte ich noch gar nicht. Ab jetzt mein neues Lieblingswort.

Comment: Lass uns der Vollständigkeit halber doch noch den Hiwi, den Assi und die Stupo aufnehmen...

Comment: @Stephie: Was ist denn die Stupo?

Comment: @chirlu Studien-und Prüfungsordnung. (Das Dokument das höchstens 10% der Studis je lesen ^_^)

Comment: @Stephie: Ach so, das waren bei uns zwei separate Dokumente, von denen keines eine geläufige Abkürzung hatte.

Comment: @Stephie Ich glaube, die Liste ist lang genug ;)

Comment: +1 für den Aküfi, ;) Auf der Liste -- lang genug hin oder her -- fehlt übrigens noch der Studi.

Answer (score 8):

Ich kann nur zu dem Teil »**Wie ist es in Österreich?**« Stellung nehmen:

»Ersti« ist zumindest mir völlig unbekannt. (Ich bin Akademiker, lebe seit 50 Jahren in Österreich, und habe mein letztes Studium erst vor sechs Jahren abgeschlossen)

Viele Abkürzungen, die in Deutschlang gängig zu sein scheinen, werden in Österreich nicht verwendet.

Ein »*Auszubildender*« heißt in Österreich nicht *Azubi*, weil es den Begriff »Auszubildender« bei uns gar nicht gibt. So jemand heißt in Österreich »*Lehrling*«. Das trifft auch auf viele andere Abkürzungen zu, weil es den juristischen Begriff in Österreich gar nicht gibt (z.B. »Hartz 4«, »BAföG«)

»Ersti« ist in diesem Zusammenhang insofern eine Ausnahme, weil es den Begriff »Erstsemestriger« durchaus auch in Österreich gibt. Dass dieser Begriff bei uns nicht verwendet wird, liegt vermutlich daran, dass die Abkürzung wegen des i am Ende ein wenig kindisch klingt.

Als ich das Wort vor wenigen Minuten in der Frage laß, war meine erste Assoziation: *Jemand, der das erste Jahr im Kindergarten (in D: »Kindertagesstätte«*)* *oder in der Volksschule (in D: Grundschule) verbringt.* An junge Erwachsene, die eine Uni besuchen, hätte ich nie im Leben gedacht.

*<sub>(Eine »Kita« gibts in Österreich auch nicht)</sub>

Comment: Achtung: Kindergärten gibt es in D durchaus, sogar schon deutlich länger als Kitas und auch noch immer. Die beiden Begriffe beschreiben unterschiedliche Dinge.

Comment: Natürlich gibt es Kindergärten in Österreich, aber sie werden im gewöhnlichen Sprachgebrauch weder  _Kindi_ noch _Kiga_ (oder überhaupt) abgekürzt ... Ansonsten erschließt sich mir als interessiertem Laien übrigens nicht, inwiefern dt. Kindertagestätten und ö. Kindergärten "unterschiedliche Dinge" sind. Beide Begriffe beschreiben Betreuungseinrichtungen für (idR noch nicht schulpflichtige) Kinder, wobei Details hier wie dort variieren können. (In Ö zB ist das Kindergartenwesen Landessache.)

Comment: Auch ihr seid vor keiner Infantilisierung sicher: http://stv-philosophie.at/ersti-tutorium-ws-1516/

Comment: Mit Kitas, Kindergärten usw. ist es kompliziert und uneinheitlich: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kindertagesst%C3%A4tte

Comment: Und auch die Volksschule gibt es in Deutschland (zumindest in Bayern), ist aber auch etwas anderes als Grundschule. (Volksschule = Grundschule + Hauptschule; Neudeutsch »Mittelschule«)

Comment: Ich habe nicht geschrieben, dass es in Deutschland keine Kindergärten oder Volksschulen gäbe. Ich wollte zum Ausdruck bringen, dass die Begriffe »Kindertagesstätte«, »Kita« und »Grundschule« in Österreich weder als amtliche Bezeichnungen, noch umgangssprachlich in Verwendung sind. Ich habe auch nicht versucht anzudeuten, deutsche Kitas wären etwas anderes als Österreichische Kindergärten, und ich habe auch mit keiner Silbe angedeutet, in Deutschland gäbe es keine Volksschulen.

Comment: Kurzfassung österreichisches Schulsystem: 0-3 Jahre: Kinder sind bei Eltern, oder bei einer Tagesmutter oder in einer Kinderkrippe. 3-6 Jahre: Kinder sind bei Eltern oder im Kindergarten. Mit 5 Jahren können die Eltern die Kinder in eine Vorschule schicken. Schulbeginn im Normalfall mit 6 Jahren. 1.-4. Schuljahr: Klasse Volksschule (für alle; Klassennummern: 1-4). Im 5. Schuljahr beginnt die Klassenzählung wieder bei 1. Es gibt: a) Hauptschule (Klassen 1-4) mit anschließendem Polytechnikum (dauert 1 Jahr, ohne Klassen-Nummer) oder b) Mittelschule (Klassen 1-8) oder AHS (Klassen 1-8).

Comment: Mittelschule und AHS (allgemeinbildende höhere Schule) schließen am Ende der 8. Klasse mit der Matura ab. Seit einigen Jahren wird ein neuer Schultyp eingeführt: die »Neue Mittelschule« soll die Hauptschule und die Unterstufe der AHS (Klasse 1-4, also 5. bis 8. Schuljahr) zusammenfassen. Hauptschule und die »alte« Mittelschule sollen verschwinden. Nach der 8. Schulstufe (4. Klasse Hauptschule, Mittelschule oder AHS) können nicht nur Hauptschüler zum Polytechnikum wechseln, sondern alle (Hauptschüler *müssen* das Poly machen). An das Poly schließt eine Lehrausbildung mit Berufsschule an.

Comment: "liegt vermutlich daran, dass die Abkürzung wegen des i am Ende ein wenig kindisch klingt" - dieser Eindruck ist auch in Deutschland nicht anders und meiner Meinung nach ein Stück weit beabsichtigt. Vorrangig wird der Begriff meiner Auffassung nach von studentischen und Gremien Hilfsorganisationen benutzt. Dazu passt relativ gut, dass durch den etwas kindischen Klang von "Ersti" ausgedrückt wird, dass aus Sicht der älteren Studenten die Erstsemester wie "Kinder" sind, und gleichzeitig gegenüber den Ersties, dass diese freundlich aufgenommen werden und sie sich wohl fühlen sollen, ...

Comment: ... freundschaftliche Kontakte knüpfen und auch Spaß an ihrem Studium haben sollen, statt alles bierernst zu nehmen und ständig Angst zu haben, dass in der Universität lauter Fremde sind, die einem den Kopf abreißen wollen. In einer offiziellen administrativen Ankündigung einer Universität würde nie die Abkürzung "Ersti" benutzt werden, in einer Einladung zu einem Kennenlernwochenende für Erstsemester hingegen durchaus.

Answer (score 2):

Es bezeichnet (verniedlicht) einen Studenten im ersten Semester. Ich kenne es auch aus Stuttgart, Karlsruhe, Berlin, Aachen und Darmstadt.

Answer (score 0):

Ich war Student an einer deutschen Universität in den 60er und 70er Jahren des letzten Jahrhunderts. Damals hatten wir schon Uni, Prof, Audimax und Asta; Studi und Ersti gab es noch nicht.